# Make INSERT,UPDATE or DELETE inside a stored procedure from one server to a table on another server

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-insert, sql-delete

I have this problem; I'm trying to execute `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` statements inside a stored procedure from one server to a table that is in another server.

Example: I have the server `192.168.0.3` with a database `BaseA`, inside I add a stored procedure `spu_a`. In this stored procedure I want to insert a new row into the table `tableAinBaseB` in database `BaseB` that is in the server `192.168.0.4`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming Microsoft SQL Server.

I think you want "cross server" or "linked server" SQL. See the MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213778%28SQL.80%29.aspx). Your queries would then use 4 part identifiers like so:

```
Select * From Server.Database.Schema.Table
```

Previous employers of mine haven't liked this solution (security reasons I was told) so enforced the use of SSIS solutions. This may be a consideration for you.

Comment: I agree, don't to to build a link between two servers like this. If you need the data from server a to server b, build a replication structure OR if you just replicate a few tables from DB-A to DB-B then do it with a SSIS project (and deploy it into a maintenance job - ms sql agent).